why loader function not called in react js?
I am using React-Router-DOM loader prop function (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader).
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path={'/ap'}
      loader={() => {
        console.log('0000');
        return 'ss';
      }}
      element={<App />}
    ></Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

When I check on console it is not called or in other words message is not printed.
Here is my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-6gg4ab?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fmain.tsx&terminal=dev
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const data = useLoaderData();
  console.log('----s', data);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>Vite + React</h1>
    </>
  );
}

I am trying to fetch some data before routing and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Route loaders only work when using Data routers, e.g. routers created using createBrowserRouter, createMemoryRouter, etc. If you would like to use the Data APIs then you'll need to convert to a Data router.
Examples:
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="/ap"
      loader={() => {
        console.log('0000');
        return 'ss';
      }}
      element={<App />}
    />
  )
);

...

<RouterProvider router={router} />

import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/ap",
    loader: () => {
      console.log('0000');
      return 'ss';
    },
    element: <App />,
  },
]);

...

<RouterProvider router={router} />

For more information see:

Picking a Router
Route loader


thanks for answers ... is there any other way to fetch data before routing..because my routing is written is like this<BrowserRouter>   <Routes>     <Route       path={'/ap'}       loader={() => {         console.log('0000');         return 'ss';       }}       element={<App />}     ></Route>   </Routes> </BrowserRouter>without createBrowserRouter function

one way is to convert routing using createBrowserRouter ... let me try higher order component...

or anyother npm package help loader functionality ...!!

@user5711656 "... fetch before routing" - Not really, no, not with RRD. You could fetch prior to navigating to this "/ap" route. You could use  a useEffect hook and fetch on app mount and make the data available to descendent components via a React Context or some global state management library like Redux.
